# Getting error on a simple query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to learn JPA with hibernate provider. below is the query which I am trying to fire:

```
   Query query=eManager.createQuery("from ShopBaseData");
   List list=query.getResultList();
```

I am getting below error when I am trying to execute the code:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBigDecimal(CharCommonAccessor.java:414)[:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSetImpl.java:548)[:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSet.java:372)[:11.2.0.3.0]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:67)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
```

Can someone please help me to understand what can be the possible cause of error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe query is not right?
Try something like this:

```
Query query=eManager.createQuery("SELECT * from ShopBaseData");
```

Comment: it does not work, gives error that unrecognizable character '*' is there in the query...

Comment: Try to use field name instead of *

Comment: JPQL does not have "SELECT *", this is not SQL. It should be "SELECT s FROM ShopBaseData s", as any JPA reference would tell

Answer (score 0):

It could be a possible mismatch between the data type mentioned in the entity and the datatype specified in db. Can you post your entity class ? How is this mapped at the database level ?